# When using kernel-side polling, how the liburing and kernel avoid lost wakeup?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, io-uring

After go through the source code,

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ff1176468d368232b684f75e82563369208bc371/fs/io_uring.c#L6907

I am confuse about the wakeup when use kernel-side polling,

user-thread: A. update-tail, then B. check-need-wakeup-flag

kernel-thread: C. set-wakeup-flag D. check tail

if the user-thread see the order: A. B. C. , and the kernel-thread see the order C. D. A. ，will cause a lost wakeup?

Comment: Please add links to the code.

Comment: Please add references to the specific places in the source code where you think there is a problem.

Comment: the link contains the line number

Comment: I guess you did not read the comments at the top of the file on use of barriers.  https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ff1176468d368232b684f75e82563369208bc371/fs/io_uring.c#L18

Comment: `sqd->ctx_list` is protected by a mutex (`sqd->lock`) that prevents the tail being updated while the thread is checking whether it needs to call `schedule()` or not.

Comment: @IanAbbott the user-thread never hold that lock, just update the tail with a release barrier, see liburing: https://github.com/axboe/liburing/blob/7758ae5ed97910ee7b66c6e4764500291f029bdf/src/include/liburing.h#L170

Comment: @stark see liburing: https://github.com/axboe/liburing/blob/7758ae5ed97910ee7b66c6e4764500291f029bdf/src/include/liburing.h#L170 ， application just update the tail with a release barrier, not a full barrier.

Comment: Shouldn't the user thread wake up the kernel thread if it sees the "needs wakeup" flag set? The `io_uring_submit` and `io_uring_submit_and_wait` functions in "liburing" seem to do that.

Comment: Yes, but my question is, the user thread may miss the flag when necessary

Comment: Perhaps, but it should get sorted out on the next submission or the next wait for completion.